# Foreign key as primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys

I have two dependent tables as

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
post_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE post_meta
(
post_id int(11) unsigned REFERENCES posts(post_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
info varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Question 1: After `INSERT`ing into `posts`, `post_meta` does not accept value with error `Duplicate entry XX for key 'PRIMARY`. How should I modify the table structure?

Question 2: How can I set to create a corresponding row in `post_meta` upon `INSERT INTO posts`? I mean creating an empty row (only having id of the FK) in `post_meta` when creating a row in `posts`. In other words having the same number of rows in two columns without any `INSERT` into the second column.

Comment: if any `post_meta` row has a `posts` row, why don't you make `post_id` FK in `post_meta`? Question2: with a trigger maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current implementation looks as out of normalized form. Are you sure you need to keep the data separated to two different tables? Maybe

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
post_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255),
info varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

will do?

Speculating: if you're doing it that way because of security issues then MySQL [supports Column-level privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges).

If normalizing your data is unacceptable for some reasons then you can just make `post_id` primary key in both tables (don't make it foreign key!) and add INSERT and DELETE triggers on table `posts` which will insert or delete corresponding rows from post_meta.

**UPDATE**

You said in comment that you can have multiple records in `post_meta` table corresponding to single record in `posts`. That changes **a lot**:

1. You MUST NOT use primary key on `post_id` in table `post_meta`. Primary key MUST be unique in table scope.
2. You can set up your foreign key (the one you already tried to) - this will ensure that metadata is deleted automatically with posts.
3. If you do need PRIMARY KEY defined on `post_meta` then you shoud add a new (possibly auto_increment field) to `post_meta` table and use it as primary key. (Also, table can exist even without primary key but it's against most DB guidelines)
4. If you need to create a meta record(s) automatically for each post then you can add an INSERT trigger on `posts` as I've already suggested. Another approach is using a stored procedure (and only stored procedure) for adding records to `posts` - and in this SP you can write some SQL to insert necessary records to `post_meta`.

Comment: This is just a simple example, the meta table contains separate information. For example several meta for different post type which will work with JOIN when needed.